# Differences between function template and lambda expression

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, auto

```
// (1)
template<typename T>
T add1(T a, T b)
{
    return a + b;
}

// (2)
auto add2 = [](auto a, auto b) 
{ 
    return a + b; 
};
```

In this simple example I was wondering which implementation is better in terms of:

- code size (in the old days templates used to cause "code bloat")
- execution speed (is there any difference for non-trivial function body ?)
- inlining friendliness (which variant is more probably to be inlined in case of a non-trivial function body ?)

Comment: I would prefer latter version. About code size, you can better profile and check yourself.

Comment: it depends, it depends , about the same.

Comment: `(1)` and `(2)` do not do the same thing. `add1(1, 3.14)` fails whereas `add2(1, 3.14)` succeeds. `(3)` would be something like `template<typename A, typename B> auto add3(A a, B b) -> decltype(a+b){return a+b;}`. C++14 lets you get away without the `->decltype()`-part.

Comment: @nwp With or without the trailing return type does make a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So recall that generic lambda basically defines a function template `operator()`, so the second version is basically:

```
struct __some_uniq_name
{
    template<typename T, typename U>
    auto operator()(T a, U b) const
    {
        return a + b;
    }
} add2;
```

The code here is the same as the code in `add1`*, except one is a member function in a local variable and the other is a free function template. There should be no difference in performance, code size, or inlining ability (but always, test test test!) - the only difference is which one you can use where. Need to add things in lots of places? Use `add1`. Need to use it in one specific location? Use `add2`.

*except that it lets you add objects of different types, so if you need to do that, you only have one option.